# nullability-completeness warning since Xcode 9.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, clang

[The "nullability-completeness" warning](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wnullability-completeness) is not working in Xcode 9.3 (and 9.4.1) for me.
It works though in Xcode 9.1 and 9.2.

I created a new iOS project in Xcode 9.2 (or 9.1) with the "Single View App" template, then add this method to my ViewController.h:

```
- (nonnull UIView *)f:(UIView *)f g:(UIView *)g;
```

I'm getting 2 warnings on each of the arguments as expected like so:

```
In file included from /Users/daniel/Projects/tests/TestNullability92/TestNullability92/ViewController.m:9:
/Users/daniel/Projects/tests/TestNullability92/TestNullability92/ViewController.h:13:31: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
- (nonnull UIView *)f:(UIView *)f g:(UIView *)g;
                              ^
/Users/daniel/Projects/tests/TestNullability92/TestNullability92/ViewController.h:13:31: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
- (nonnull UIView *)f:(UIView *)f g:(UIView *)g;
                              ^
                               _Nullable
/Users/daniel/Projects/tests/TestNullability92/TestNullability92/ViewController.h:13:31: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
- (nonnull UIView *)f:(UIView *)f g:(UIView *)g;
```

But if I open and rebuild that project in Xcode 9.3 (or 9.4.1) - I don't get those warnings.

I tried going to the build settings and enabling this flag explicitly (although it should be enabled by default), but still got nothing:

[image]

Comment: Same issue on Xcode 9.4.1.

Comment: I see the same issue on Xcode 10.0. Any fixes for this? I would like to get a warning for nullability (in)completeness.

Comment: I still keep Xcode 9.2 for this purpose. We should report this to Apple.

Comment: Reported to bugreport.apple.com with problemID 45399704

Comment: the current Xcode beta (10.2) seems to show these warnings again. And you can't turn them of with -Wno-nullability-completeness ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug with Xcode from 9.3 to 10.1 that no-nullability-completeness flag did not work as expected.

This was fixed in Xcode 10.2, it produces the right warnings again: if the flag is enabled (it should be enabled by default), the pointer object arguments and return values in header files are required to have nullability annotations (or be inside NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN blocks). If the annotations are missing, the compiler warning is produced as expected.

Comment: No idea what "produces the right warnings" is supposed to mean. It's extremely unclear from the question whether you want those warnings or not and what versions produce and not prodice them.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I've updated the answer. Please ask more questions if there's still more misunderstandings.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is really simple (no need to file a bug).

---

> In your Project Build Settings simply search for "Custom Compiler
>   Flags", and add the following:
>
> `-Wno-nullability-completeness`

[image]

---

If you are trying to **show** the warnings, try adding this flag, clean & build, then remove the flag (clean and build again..). If this doesn't work it may

Perhaps the removal of these warnings are not so much a *bug*, but rather a purposeful hiding of these errant messages in an effort to clean up projects and their error messages.

Comment: Your proposed solution seems to help, if you want to deactivate the warning, right? I think battlmonstr tries to activate the warnings, which should not be necessary since they should be activated by default. But I have the same problem. I would be very interested if you could tell us how to activate them, since -Wnullability-completeness does not work.

Comment: Oh - the OP seems misleading as it suggests strongly from the title since Xcode 9.3 there are no warnings. Update to Xcode 10 and see if they appear. Xcode has even included now in all new files NULL flags at top and bottom to silence these warning programmatically